# FILTER OLAP CUBE WITH VBA

Tags: filter, olap

I am trying to update an OLAP pivotfilter with the value of another cell (not in a pivot table).

The code I have is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when 
'cell C1 or C2 is touched
If Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewStock As String

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotFilter")
'The activesheet is named "Top1_Value"
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("[StockCode].[Stock Code_SKU].[Stock Code_SKU]")
NewStock = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.VisibleItemsList = NewStock
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Any assistance to resolve would be appreciated.

Comment: My apologies, error I am receiving is Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.  I can't seem to see where I am going wrong.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].